# From command line tool to cocoa application

Tags: xcode, datepicker, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm beginning to explore programming in objective-c and I wrote a few lines of code for a command line tool. It works but now I'm trying to rewrite it in Cocoa application and I have some problems. This is the working code of the single line tool:

```
 //Formattazione delle date preimpostate
    NSDateFormatter *formatoData = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatoData setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    //Definizione della data di inizio e della data di fine
    NSDate * dataInizio = [formatoData dateFromString:datePicker];

    //Risultato
    NSString *risultato=[dataInizio descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%w" timeZone:nil locale:nil];

    //Output
    NSLog(@"Il giorno impostato è %@", risultato);
```

To create the Cocoa application, I have created an objective-C class I called VisualizzaClasse.
VisualizzaClasse.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface VisualizzaClasse : NSObject
{
    IBOutlet NSDatePicker *datePicker;
    IBOutlet NSTextView *textView;}
- (IBAction)mostraRisultato:(id)sender;

@end
```

VisualizzaClasse.m:

```
#import "VisualizzaClasse.h"

@implementation VisualizzaClasse

- (IBAction)mostraRisultato:(id)sender;
{
     //Formattazione delle date preimpostate

        NSDateFormatter *formatoData = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatoData setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        //Definizione della data di inizio e della data di fine
   NSDate * dataInizio = [formatoData dateFromString:datePicker];

        //Risultato
        NSString *risultato=[dataInizio descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%w" timeZone:nil locale:nil];

    [textView insertText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n", risultato]];
}


@end
```

The interface is composed of a DatePicker, TextView and by a button.I can not make the DatePicker replace dateFromString.The error is: incompatible pointer type sending 'NSDatePicker _strong *' to parameter of type 'NSString *', at the line:

```
NSDate * dataInizio = [formatoData dateFromString:datePicker];
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the NSDatePicker correctly hooked up in InterfaceBuilder so it is connected to DatePicker.

If so, you should be able to assign as follows:

```
NSDate * unformattedDate = [ datePicker dateValue ];
```

And then do your formatting as before, using `unformattedDate` as the input to your formatter.

Answer (score 0):

dateFromString method requires NSString, your parameter type is NSDatePicker

Use NSDate *dateVariable = datePicker.date; instead dateFromString if you need to convert it to NSDate

Once you have NSDate, you could use the formatter as mentioned from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: In fact, if replace dataPicker with @"07/04/2012"it works, but I want to use the datePicker to set the desired date.

Comment: so you can use datePicker.date instead dateFromString call

Comment: I tried:NSDate * dataInizio = [formatoData datePicker.date];but does not work.

Comment: First you have NSDate and then use the formatter on NSDate as mentioned from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html